# .htaccess rewriting URLs that don't exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Currently, I'm working with some guys that love short URLs for marketing purposes when posting to social media.

They have `https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder`

For their marketing, they would like `https://www.example.com/mysuperbuzzword` which would point to the first URL but in the browser, you would still see the shorter URL.

My first thought was "I'll just add a rewrite rule in the `.htaccess`"

Something like `Redirect 301 /mysuperbuzzword /folder/subfolder/` which would work but then the URL changes.

I did some reading and discovered the `[P]` flag. Then I tried this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vanityurl
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/subfolder [P]`

The issue I have now is that because `/vanityurl` doesn't exist, instead of rewriting, I just get a 404 error.

I've been testing my rule using a .htaccess rule checking tool and the URL it spits out looks correct, but again, I just get a 404.

[image]

Also, if you use the flag `[PT]` the resource is found but the URL is changed in the address bar.

Comment: Just add a trailing slash in the RewriteRule with the proxy flag. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/vanityurl
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/subfolder/ [P]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tested with a permanent redirect. Never do that. It is cached by the browser, and the browser will no longer do requests to the server. This is possible, because such a redirect is supposed to be... well... permanent. If you must test redirects, test them with a temporary redirect (302) and change them later if everything turns out to be fine.

With mod_rewrite you can do three things:

- Do an internal rewrite. If you internally rewrite *url a* to *url b*, then the user sees *url a*, but *url b* is being executed on the server.
- Do an external redirect. If you externally redirect *url a* to *url b* you send back a response: "Please request *url b* instead.". The browser then sends another request to the server with *url b* and changes the url in the address bar accordingly.
- Do a proxy request. If you proxy *url a* to *url b*, the user requests *url a*. The server then opens a http connection and requests *url b*. It then waits for the response and channels that back to the client. It is very expensive to do such a thing via mod_rewrite.

What you simply want to do is:

```
RewriteRule ^vanityurl$ /folder/subfolder [L]
```

It as a simple internal rewrite.